# What is the purpose for the tag "saw"? Should it be replaced on questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just called up the tag "saw" to review info on its tag wiki and discovered that it has been used 13 times and has no descriptive tag wiki.  There are also a lot of other "saw" related tags such as hand saw, table saw etc.  My thinking is that this tag is not useful and in each case the tag could be replaced with a more specific and useful one.  I would be inclined to review all of the related questions and retag them more appropriately, but wanted some feedback before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, given "saw" is such an incredibly broadly-applicable and generic term.